Вложенный callback в телеграмм боте
Кнопка Магазин не работает, можете подсказать, почему?
Пробовал менять уровень вложенности, ничего не помогало.
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Брак', callback_data='B'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Рецепты', callback_data='R'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Отзывы и предложения', callback_data='O'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сотрудничество', callback_data='C'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'приветственный текст', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callbackmessage(callback):
    '''обработка кнопки БРАК'''
    if callback.data == 'B':
        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Магазин', callback_data='Shop')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Маркетплейс', callback_data='Marketplace')
        markup1.row(btn1, btn2)

        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Спасибо, что написали нам! Нам очень жаль, что так произошло. Позвольте нам исправить данное недоразумение. <b>Не спешите оставлять отрицательный отзыв на маркетплейсе! Мы компенсируем ваши затраты на бракованную продукцию!</b>', parse_mode='html')
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Позвольте уточнить, где вы покупали нашу продукцию?', reply_markup=markup1)

        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
        def SorM(callback):
            if callback.data == 'Shop':
                bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'магазин')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

А зачем ВООБЩЕ использовать вложенные обработчики, что бы что?(так делать не надо)

@Amgarak прав. Для каждой кнопки должен быть свой хендлер, если, конечно, они не выполняют одинаковые функции. Стоит изучить язык прежде, чем лезть в ботов.
